# HOST_NAME is 127.0.0.1 (gunicorn via Apache)

Tags: django, apache, gunicorn

I managed to get gunicorn running behind Apache:

```
<Location /foo/>
    ProxyPass unix:/run/gunicorn-foo.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
    ProxyPassReverse unix:/run/gunicorn-foo.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
</Location>
```

Everything works, except ALLOWED_HOSTS checking. The HTTP_HOST is always 127.0.0.1

How to pass the HTTP_HOST to gunicorn?

```
Apache/2.4.46 (Debian)
```

BTW: I would prefer Nginx, but that's not possible in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Location /foo/>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
    ProxyPass unix:/run/gunicorn-foo.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
    ProxyPassReverse unix:/run/gunicorn-foo.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
</Location>
```